# basic oracle question

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql

I have this query:

```
select total.lecgrouplecture(l.groupcode)  lecturename,
       total.lecgrouptime(l.groupcode) lecttime 
  from total.lecgroup l  
 where term = (select term 
                from total.CURENTTERM) 
   and rownum < 10 
order by lecturename
```

I want to know what `total.lecgrouptime(l.groupcode)` is, and get this information from where?

Comment: Please use Upper Case Letters to Begin Sentences.

Answer (score 1):

total is the package name

lecgrouplecture is a function within that package

Look in user_source for the code or use a GUI like SQL Developer or TOAD

Comment: thanks.
i user this query to see inside user source:
SELECT * FROM User_Source but i cant see anything about lecgrouplecture.

Comment: select text from user_source where name = 'TOTAL' order by line; 

It could be that you are not the owner of the package: 

select text from all_source where name = 'TOTAL' order by line;

Answer (score 0):

it looks like TOTAL is the name of a schema (`SELECT * FROM all_users WHERE username = 'TOTAL'`). If this is the case then `lecgrouplecture` must be a pl/sql function. You will find what it does with [Robert](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1578174/basic-oracle-question/1578203#1578203)'s query:

```
SELECT * 
  FROM all_source 
 WHERE owner = 'TOTAL' 
   AND name = 'LECGROUPLECTURE' 
 ORDER BY line;
```

Comment: @Vincent: thanks =). I'm so used to writing packages I didn't even consider it could be a standalone function.